# Sum to infinity of the geometric progression

Tags: recurrence-relations, geometric-series, geometric-progressions

The terms of an infinite series ***S*** are formed by adding together the corresponding terms in two infinite geometric series, ***T*** and ***U***.

The first term of **T** and the first term of **U** are each **4**.

In order, the first three terms of the combined series ***S*** are **8**, **3**, and **5/4**.

What is the sum to infinity of ***S***?

I have no clue on how to solve this and will be grateful for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

$T_1 = 4, U_1 = 4$

$T_2 + U_2 =3$

$T_3 + U_3 = 5/4$

Also, as $T$ and $U$ are geometric series',

$T_2 = 4r_t$ 
$U_2 = 4r_u$

(where $r_t$ an $r_u$ are the ratios for those geometric series;)

$T_3 = 4r_t^2$
$U_3 = 4r_u^2$

So,

$4r_t + 4r_u = 3$

$4r_t^2 + 4r_u^2 = 5/4$

We now have simultaeneous equations in $r_u$ and $r_t$. You should be able to do the rest, I think.

Comment: Yes, this does make sense, thank you!